# Laravel Ajax create data return Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-500

I tried to input data with images using laravel and ajax, but got an error 500 (internal server error) im not sure with my code, can somebody help me please, thanyou

This Is my Blade

```
   <form id="appForm">
              
                     <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" class="form-control" aria-describedby="id" value="">
                     <input type="hidden" id="photo_update" name="photo_update" class="form-control" aria-describedby="photo_update" value="">

                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Foto</label>
                            <input type="file" id="photo" class="form-control @error('photo') is-invalid @enderror" name="photo" placeholder="foto" accept="image/*">
                            @error('photo')
                                   <small class="form-text text-danger"></small>
                            @enderror
                     </div> 

                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Judul Gallery</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" aria-describedby="name" value="">
                            @error('name')
                                   <small class="form-text text-danger"></small>
                            @enderror
                     </div>


                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Deskripsi Gallery</label>
                            <textarea id="description" name="description" id="description" class="form-control tiny" rows="3"></textarea>
                            @error('description')
                                   <small  class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                            @enderror
                     </div>
                     {{-- <button type="sumbit" id="saveButton" name="send" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="send" value="Kirimkan Pesan">Simpan Gallery Perusahaan</button> --}}
                                                             
       
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                            <button type="submit" name="send" id="saveButton" value="Kirimkan Data" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                     </div>
              </form>
```

This is my model

```
protected $fillable =[
        'photo',
        'name',
        'description',
    ];
```

This Is My Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=$request->All();
       //  dd($data);
        if ($request->photo_update !== null && $request->photo == null){
             $namaFile=$request->photo_update;
        }else{
            Storage::delete('public/images/gallery'.$request->photo);
            if ($request->hasFile('photo')){
                $slug=Str::slug($request['name']);
                $extFile=$request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $namaFile=$slug.'-'.time().".".$extFile;
                $request->photo->storeAs('public/images/gallery',$namaFile);  
            }else{
                $namaFile='defaultPhoto.jpg';
            }   
        }
        $data['slug']=Str::slug($request->name);
        $data['photo']=$namaFile;
        Gallery::updateOrCreate(['id'=>$request->id],$data);
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

And This is my AJAX

```
        $("#saveButton").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            var form = $('#appForm')[0];
            var data = new FormData(form);
            $('#saveButton').html(`<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Mengirim`);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", //karena simpan kita pakai method POST
                    enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                    url: "{{route('gallery.store')}}", //url simpan data
                    data:data, //panggil form yang sudah dideklarasikan diatas
                    dataType: 'json', //data tipe kita kirim berupa JSON
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 600000,
                    success: function (data) { //jika berhasil 
                        $('#appForm').trigger("reset"); //form reset
                        $('#appModal').modal('hide'); //modal hide
                        $('#saveButton').html('Simpan'); //tombol simpan
                        var oTable = $('#appTable').dataTable(); //inialisasi datatable
                        oTable.fnDraw(false); //reset datatable
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Berhasil',
                            text: 'Data Sukses ditambahkan!',
                            showConfirmButton:false,
                            timer: 1500
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (data) { //jika error tampilkan error pada conso
                        console.log((data.responseJSON.errors));
                    }
                });
            });
```

tried to input data with images using laravel and ajax, but got an error 500, Can somebody help me please, thank you

Comment: 500 error is a server side error, you need to debug the error at least, otherwise no one can help you. Check your console and the error logs (/storage/log/) to get the error

Comment: if you are using your console to see error, double click on error to see actual laravel message or go to network tab you can see that there too